# how to move all files from subfolder into parent github

Tags: github, create-react-app, github-pages

I have github repo **myrepo** and **myapp-app** inside. Is there any way to move all contents from **myapp-app** to **myrepo** or just get rid of parent folder? I have a problem with deploying gh-pages due to it.

It is one of my first react apps and by mistake I created a folder first, initialized git repo and then created app inside.

To sum up:
Structure I have:
my github profile -> myrepo -> myapp-app

Structure I want to have:
my github profile -> myapp-app

Comment: The suggestion about using `git (e.g., `git mv`) to move files should relocate, but a related Q on `gh-pages`.

Are you trying to have the page as <username>.github.io/myapp-app? If so this will require a rename of the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you have repo in github then clone it from there, make the required changes i.e change it to the desired folder structure, then commit those changes and push it to github.

Answer (score 0):

I have just moved all files and folders into parent folder and commit changes. It simply works. I just used drag and drop but probably there is a git command for that.